# DHIS2 - How to attach files in event captures?

Tags: dhis2

I've been working with the event capture in dhis2 and looks like it is far less polished than the "data entry" part. Right now in the data entry if you choose to use a data element of type "file" a button to upload the file appears there.

When you use a data element of type "file" on event capture a text field appears instead (and looks like it expects the id of the file to be put there), but no way to upload the file first. The only way I've seen to do this is to first upload the file inside the form using the dhis api, retrieve the id and put it automatically on the field (but still quite not sure about how this could be done).

I was wondering if there was an easier way or if someone faced the same problem or if there is an easier way that I missed to do this. (seems like quite a complex way to just upload a file)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which version of DHIS 2 are you referring to? File upload in event capture was in fact implemented in version 2.22. Perhaps you could download the latest version of the software and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been greatly improved in DHIS version 2.24. I recommend that you upgrade your DHIS version and try again. In 2.24 you can simply click the file icon next to each data entry input field and upload your file.